# Update context from another context in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I'm facing an issue with how I'm using the ContextAPI in a ReactJS app.
I want to have something like this:

```
<App>
 <Alerts/>
 <MyComponent />
</App>
```

I have a context that will manage Alerts with something like this:

```
  const initialState = [];

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(alertReducer, initialState);

  const setAlert = alert => {
    const id = uuidv4();

    dispatch({
      type: SET_ALERT,
      payload: { ...alert, id },
    });
  };
```

Then I will have some action in other context such as:

```
 const getErrors = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get( .... ) 
    dispatch({ type: CLEAR, payload: res });
  };
```

Is there any way so that in clearErrors I can dispatch an action to the alert context?

Basically I want to be able to update a state in a different context.

I'm trying to have a toast manager...and send "toasts" when an action goes with success or error in some axios functions.

I'm afraid I can be somehow complicating this, but I've tried to find some light in google searchs, but I only find share state between components, but no update states from different contexts.

With redux, as we have a centralized store we can dispatch an action that all reducers catch, but with contextapi that doesn't happen....

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter, how many contexts you have in the the App, you can always target the correct context as long as you have its provider higher up in the hierarchy

For instance, if `AlertContextProvider` wraps the component that calls getErrors then you can definitely target alerts

Assuming `MyComponent` calls `getErrors` and `Alerts` component is the Provider, your structure would be

```
<App>
   <Alerts>
      <MyComponent />
   </Alerts>
</App>
```

Now in myComponent you need to use useContext with AlertContext and then call dispatch

```
const [data, dispatch] = useContext(AlertContext);

const getErrors = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get( .... ) 
    dispatch({ type: CLEAR, payload: res });
  };
```

Comment: the issue is that getErrors is in another context, let's call it "MyComponentContext" And what I wanted was a clear way that this context gets in "touch" with alertContext...since the action is async and I don't want to do a await in the component...(that would access both contexts)

Comment: You can wrap your App with AlertContext, so that you can use it anywhere because unless you have a provider in hierarchy you can't access that context value

Comment: our solution was to wrap useReducer with a useReducerWithExtras and then use the alert context in this.